# SVM Classification: Confidence Interval

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

Is it possible to get a Z-score from sklearn's svm implementation?

So, if it classifies inputs X as [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0], could you get it to output: [0.5,0.78,0.95,0.11,0.34,...], where these are the estimated confidences the learner has in its predictions?

If I implemented it myself, would I be able to extract this info, or would it turn into a huge project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know SVM's don't have a closed-form Z-score, however if you create your `SVC` with the parameter `probability=True`, it will include a probability model constructed using cross-validation which you can access using `predict_proba`, to get an estimate of the confidence of the predictions.

Comment: Awesome, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.